# Query para atualizar campo de uma tabela com base em outra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia, estou precisando atualizar os valores de uma tabela com base nos valores que estão em outra.

Preciso que a primeira tabela atualize somente os dados contido na segunda, por exemplo, na primeira tabela tenho 3 mil itens e na segunda 330, então preciso atualizar somente 330 itens.

Acredito que pra fazer isso tenho que usar `SELECT` encadeado então montei algo assim:

```
SELECT lvi.IdProduto, lvi.VlCustoUnitario
FROM LoteInventarioItem lvi
WHERE lvi.IdProduto IN (SELECT pe.IdProduto FROM Produto_Empresa pe)
```

Essa query me traz os 330 itens porém preciso atualizar o campo `lvi.vlCustoUnitario` com o dados da segunda tabela contidos em `pe.VlPrecoCusto`.

Comment: Poderia dar detalhes das tabelas?

Comment: Na tabela "LoteInventarioItem" possui um campo de custo unitário "VlCustoUnitario" que está zerado, porém tenho esses dados na tabela de "Produto_Empresa" no campo "VlPrecoCusto". Essas tabelas não possuem relacionamento direto, porém o campo IdProduto se repete nas duas, então basicamente preciso comparar os ID's das duas e onde for igual, atualizar os dados.

Comment: @RonaldoAlves Em alguma das tabelas há a possibilidade de ter mais de uma linha com o mesmo valor de IdProduto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) *preciso atualizar o campo lvi.vlCustoUnitario com o dados da segunda tabela contidos em pe.VlPrecoCusto.*

Esboço do código, considerando-se que não há linhas repetidas pela coluna `IdProduto`:

```
-- código #1
UPDATE LVI
  set vlCustoUnitario= PE.VlPrecoCusto
  from Produto_Empresa as PE
       inner join LoteInventarioItem as LVI on LVI.IdProduto = PE.IdProduto
  where ...;
```